# Django login пользователя вместо id в профиле кастомного пользователя

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Как использовать login вместо id при обращении к профилю пользователя[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

views.py

```
class userProfileDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user'
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerProfileOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("all-profiles", UserProfileListCreateView.as_view(), name="all-profiles"),
    path("profile/<str:user>/", userProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile"),
]
```

serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ('id', 'login',  'email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'password')


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    user = UserCreateSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: `lookup_field = 'user__login'` не работает?

Comment: Спасибо большое) Помогло в urls  path("profile/<user__login>/", userProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile"),

Answer (score 0):

Если не сработает `lookup_field = 'user__login', то можете переопределить` get_object()` вьюхи:

```
    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(user__login=self.request.kwargs['user'])
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```